# Build and Archive Is Disabled

Tags: xcode

I've read every other thread on this and have tried everything but the "Build and Archive" function is determined not to be clicked.

I am running OSX 10.6.7 and Xcode 3.2.4. I am developing a MAC application and am trying to submit it to the Mac App Store, but to do this i need to run the Build and Archive feature, and I simply cannot figure out how to get it to run. I have heard about these "developer tools 1.1" from some other thread but cannot find those either. If you are about to say that that will fix things, then please link me, otherwise, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

P.S. Yes im in Release Mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another answer could be that your active SDK should be set to Device not to simulator. You can find this setting in Project > Set Active SDK > Device.

Happy Coding..!

Comment: Now you need to pick a scheme and hardware destination with the toolbar scheme drop-down (or go to Product / Edit Scheme).

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out... In order to Build and Archive with a Mac App (as opposed to iOS) you need Xcode 3.2.5 (maybe even 3.2.6) or better. So to all those with the same problem, make sure you are running the lasest version before trying ot Build and Archive.